# Instance delete: There is an operation pending for this application. Please wait and try again

Tags: google-app-engine

One of my instances in GAE Standard (Java) is somehow in a strange state. Trying to delete it results in "There is an operation pending for this application. Please wait and try again" for a long time now. Is there any resolution for this short of redeploying a new version?

interesting:
[Error mapping custom domain on Appengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46441659/error-mapping-custom-domain-on-appengine): This guy has the same error with a different task, but also just now. Google status says everything is ok, but its an interesting coincidence.

Comment: I now deployed a new version, stopped the old version, and the instance is gone. So that works, but needs a whole new deployment. I would still be very interested if there is a way that does not need a developer to deploy a version, eg something that could be done by an operations guy.

Comment: Just got the same thing again. Am I the only one getting these type of errors?